# Determining if two geometric figures are approximately equal using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, geometry

I would like to know how to determine if two geometric figures (the_geom) are approximately equals.

By the way, I'm working with Python, PostgreSQL and Postgis

I have the following geometries:

0101000020110F0000**FE546AD2**413E5EC1**6D56617C**93C74FC1

0101000020110F0000**9D7E6384**413E5EC1**0185DD7F**93C74FC1

When I see both figures on the map, the variation is imperceptible.

Any idea?

Comment: You're not going to be able to evaluate in WKB hexadecimal notation.  You'll need to instantiate geometries and perform a functional 'diff' (buffer one by a small threshold then see if the other is WITHIN it)

Comment: Oh, and you'll probably need to go the other way (buffer *other* and test within *one*, so that incomplete overlap is found)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Might want to try HausdorffDistance.  Suited for this kind of question.

```
SELECT ST_HausdorffDistance('0101000020110F0000FE546AD2413E5EC16D56617C93C74FC1'::geometry, '0101000020110F00009D7E6384413E5EC10185DD7F93C74FC1'::geometry);
```

Detailed here:

http://postgis.net/docs/ST_HausdorffDistance.html

And as explained at [/wiki/Hausdorff_distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance):

> Informally, two sets are close in the Hausdorff distance if every point of either set is close to some point of the other set. The Hausdorff distance is the longest distance you can be forced to travel by an adversary who chooses a point in one of the two sets, from where you then must travel to the other set. In other words, it is the greatest of all the distances from a point in one set to the closest point in the other set.