# Determine if two geometries are similar in shape and location

Tags: postgis, geojson, geometry, turf

Suppose I have two geometries that have almost identical location and shape. I say almost on purpose here, since one or the other might have an extra node, or the order of coordinates in GeoJSON might differ. But is there a way to still determine their similarity, using either `@turf` utilities or PostGIS methods, perhaps within a certain error margin?

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144714/determining-if-two-geometric-figures-are-approximately-equal-using-postgis. Search from the old questions with term "similarity" gives also other hits which may be useful.

Comment: One very basic method using `turf` would be to compute area of both polygons with `area` method, then do intersection of polygons with `intersect` method, compute area of intersection and compare the results.